# Communication between 2 TFS Application Tiers

Tags: tfs

**The Setup:**
2 application tiers (one in the DMZ (application tier used by developers), one in the LAN (application tier I use to test things) connect to the same data tier located in the LAN. The main application tier in the DMZ had the TFS proxy feature installed initially, it was removed since the feature wasn't needed.
Both application tiers run on Windwos Server 2016, version TFS2017.0.1, and connect to a SQL Server 2014.

**The Issue:**
Accessing a Project in the web interface occasionally (usually 1-2 times a day, when they are first accessed) does not work, the browser attempts to load a page for multiple minutes until an ajax error is displayed (see below).

The event viewer shows a large amount of errors, consisting of 3 repeating messages (full event log messages included below):

- System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server  *(dropped by the firewall, opening the port makes little sense, since this communication shouldn't be necessary as far as I'm aware)*
- GetInstalledExtensionStates:: Manifest not found but including as error.
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.RequestCanceledException: TF400733: The request has been canceled: Client disconnected

These last 2 error messages appear multiple times, the firewall sees the attempted connection between application tiers every few seconds while the page is stuck loading.

The issue/connection attempts continue even if the second application tier is not running and not listed as an active application tier.
This connection is only being attempted by the server which previously had a TFS proxy configured, the issue cannot be reproduced when accessing the web page on the second application tier.

Even with the error messages, I cannot find any attempt at a solution for this online.

Does anyone know why the ex-proxy still attempts to connect to the other application tier, and possibly how to stop that from happening? I don't think allowing these connections is a long term solution, even if it may help for now.

**Error messages:**

Ajax timeout error shown on the TFS Webpage:

```
Error(s):
Ajax request has been timed out.
TFS.Core.Ajax.AjaxTimeoutException: Ajax request has been timed out.
    at at (https://[Public URL]/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-common-vftORLcelTgjRkChaFEvvRgGeGkqNbmN9f9JjakT0rR0=:123:5805)
    at https://[Public URL]/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-common-vftORLcelTgjRkChaFEvvRgGeGkqNbmN9f9JjakT0rR0=:123:1356
    at rt (https://[Public URL]/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-common-vftORLcelTgjRkChaFEvvRgGeGkqNbmN9f9JjakT0rR0=:123:938)
    at Object.error (https://[Public URL]/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-common-vftORLcelTgjRkChaFEvvRgGeGkqNbmN9f9JjakT0rR0=:123:1308)
    at j (https://[Public URL]/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-basejs-vLDQ_BPnMflh1yV4rhP43SsHlun31XvwYB1svh7haP9E=:3:26860)
    at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (https://[Public URL]/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-basejs-vLDQ_BPnMflh1yV4rhP43SsHlun31XvwYB1svh7haP9E=:3:27673)
    at x (https://[Public URL]/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-basejs-vLDQ_BPnMflh1yV4rhP43SsHlun31XvwYB1svh7haP9E=:5:11145)
    at Object.abort (https://[Public URL]/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-basejs-vLDQ_BPnMflh1yV4rhP43SsHlun31XvwYB1svh7haP9E=:5:8987)
    at https://[Public URL]/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-basejs-vLDQ_BPnMflh1yV4rhP43SsHlun31XvwYB1svh7haP9E=:5:10539
Session Id: e174ae85-a447-4d6d-b1ab-846ad6db08ee
```

Event log message for failed connection to the other application tier:

```
[ TraceId]  {00000001-0001-0001-0000-000000000000}  
   Tracepoint 10013082 

   ServiceHost {F6E9CD99-1C96-47A8-B0A8-2BD83198E917} 

   ContextId 332114 

   ProcessName w3wp 

   Username [Domain User trying to connect] 

   VSID {FA945849-5329-4DFA-A13B-0108C2113593} 

   Service Web Access 

   Method Project.Home.index 

   Area ContributionManifestService 

   Layer Service 

   UserAgent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.62 Safari/537.36 

   Uri [TFS Project Uri] 

   Path 

   UniqueIdentifier {B936D264-A314-488F-BA9F-580ABBABA835} 

   UserDefined 

   ExceptionType System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException 

   Message System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while 
   sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to 
   the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 
   A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly               
   respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because 
   connected host has failed to respond [IP of second application tier]:443 
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at 
   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, 
   Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, 
   ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception) 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at 
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at 
   System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar) -- 
   - End of inner exception stack trace --- at                      
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at 
   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpMessageHandler. 
   <SendAsync>d__17.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location 
   where exception was thrown --- at 
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase. 
   <SendAsync>d__45.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location 
   where exception was thrown --- at 
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at 
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Gallery.Types.Server.PublishedExtensionCache.<GetExtensionAsset>d__5.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ExtensionManagement.Server.ContributionManifestService.LoadManifest(IVssRequestContext requestContext, String publisherName, String extensionName, String version, String language, String accountToken) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ExtensionManagement.Server.ContributionManifestService.<>c__DisplayClass3_2.<TryGetManifest>b__1(String requestedCulture) at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ExtensionManagement.Server.ContributionManifestService.TryGetManifest(IVssRequestContext requestContext, String publisherName, String extensionName, String version, String accountToken, ExtensionManifest& extensionManifest)
```

2nd event log message (manifest not found):

```
[ TraceId]  {00000001-0001-0001-0000-000000000000}  
   Tracepoint 10013622 

   ServiceHost {C72BAB51-D8CF-44DB-B3A3-F8B3EC11D13B} 

   ContextId 332110 

   ProcessName w3wp 

   Username [Domain User trying to connect] 

   VSID {FA945849-5329-4DFA-A13B-0108C2113593} 

   Service Web Access 

   Method Project.Home.index 

   Area InstalledExtensionService 

   Layer Service 

   UserAgent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.62 Safari/537.36 

   Uri [TFS Project Uri]  

   Path 

   UniqueIdentifier {B936D264-A314-488F-BA9F-580ABBABA835} 

   UserDefined 

   ExceptionType 

   Message GetInstalledExtensionStates:: Manifest not found but including as error. Adding to results: ms.vss-build. Version: 15.105.148441404 Flags: BuiltIn, MultiVersion, Trusted
```

3rd event log message (client disconnected)

```
[TraceId]  {00000001-0001-0001-0000-000000000000}  
   Tracepoint 10013082 

   ServiceHost {F6E9CD99-1C96-47A8-B0A8-2BD83198E917} 

   ContextId 332114 

   ProcessName w3wp 

   Username [Domain User trying to connect] 

   VSID {FA945849-5329-4DFA-A13B-0108C2113593} 

   Service Web Access 

   Method Project.Home.index 

   Area ContributionManifestService 

   Layer Service 

   UserAgent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.62 Safari/537.36 

   Uri [TFS Project Uri]

   Path 

   UniqueIdentifier {B936D264-A314-488F-BA9F-580ABBABA835} 

   UserDefined 

   ExceptionType Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.RequestCanceledException 

   Message 
   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.RequestCanceledException: 
   TF400733: The request has been canceled: Client disconnected.. at 
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.VssRequestContext.CheckCanceled(Boolean throwIfShutdown) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.VssRequestContext.get_ServiceProvider() at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.VssRequestContextExtensions.GetService[TService](IVssRequestContext context) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ExtensionManagement.Server.ContributionManifestService.TryGetManifest(IVssRequestContext requestContext, String publisherName, String extensionName, String version, String accountToken, ExtensionManifest& extensionManifest)
```

Comment: Do both app tiers have internet access? It looks like one of the app tiers is attempting to check the extension marketplace for updates.

Comment: Yes, both app tiers are connected to the internet and are successfully calling home (at least they are connecting tho IPs associated with Microsoft/Azure/VSTS). The first error message specifically lists the internal IP of app tier 2 as the remote server in question.

Answer (score 0):

### Update/Solution (but not really an answer):

Since the loading issues were starting to affect work quality, I completely uninstalled TFS and reinstalled it (without the proxy feature).
The loading issues no longer occur, and the associated error messages no longer appear.

While there seems to be some remaining communication between an ex-proxy and the once-configured app tier, entirely removing TFS fixes the issue.

However, it still doesn't exactly explain *why* the ex-proxy would still be attempting to connect to the other app tier.

In short: If you configure a TFS Proxy, don't try to configure it as an app tier and then remove the proxy, things will break.